# PowerGrep Search and Replace: "cannot make replacements using read-only converters"

Tags: search, replace, powergrep

I get an error on PowerGrep software when I try to Replace the content of some files: "cannot make replacements using read-only converters"

What can I do? Can anyone help me a little bit?

Comment: are the files read-only per chance?

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution:

In the left menu, on **`File formats to convert to plain text`**, you have to choose from that combo "Writable proprietary formats".

Then, press the section **`[...]`** and add NEW (format). In my case, I add .txt. Click ok. And then run "REPLACE"